# grep regex unexpected match - literal matches against number

Tags: regex, grep

Why does the following literal string

```
1998-${year}
```

..match against the grep command:

```
grep "[0-9 ]*-[ 0-9]*"  filename.txt ?
```

What I need is a regex to match any of the following strings containing either a year range or one value of year only.

```
sdkfmslf 1998-2008
asdassdadsa 1998 - 2008
mkklml mklsmdf 2006
```

..but NOT this one:

```
asdsad a s 1998-${year}
```

Comment: Try using anchors: `"^[0-9 ]*-[ 0-9]*$"` and maybe change the `*` to `+`

Comment: Your command would even match `-`.

Comment: because `*` is "match zero to infinity times" and in this case it's 0. Do you mean `+` meaning "match 1 to infinity times"?

Comment: the hyphenated numbers are part of a line in text. This is not the only content on each line.

Answer (score 0):

`*` means "match zero or more".  You want `+` which means "one or more."

```
grep "[0-9 ]+-[0-9]+"  filename.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `[0-9]{4}(\s*-\s*[0-9]{4})?`.  This will match a 4 digit number, or if it is followed by (optional white space)-(optional whitespace) then that must be followed by another 4 digit number.

Your string "asdsad a s 1998-${year}" would still match, since it has a single 4 digit value in it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like answering my own question, but none of the above worked. Here is what I found by experimenting. I'm sure there could be more elegant solutions, but here is a working version:

```
 grep "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][ ]*[\-]*[ ]*[0-9]*"  filename.txt
```